# How to avoid memory leaks in Android/Kotlin activities

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks

My app module starts a location tracker/prompter running as a foreground service. I works well, but Android Studio is giving me this warning:

```
private lateinit var locationActivity: Activity
=> Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak
```

Here is the module code:

```
package com.DevID.AppID

import android.Manifest
import android.app.*
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.Looper
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.google.android.gms.location.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.concurrent.fixedRateTimer

private var createCount = 0
private var initialized = false
private var LocationServiceRunning = false
private var locationService: LocationService = LocationService()
private lateinit var locationIntent: Intent

private lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
private lateinit var VolleyQueue: RequestQueue
private lateinit var locationActivity: Activity // **WARNING: Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak**

fun startLocationService(activity: Activity, enable: Boolean) {
    LocationService.Enabled = enable
    locationIntent = Intent(activity, locationService.javaClass)
    VolleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
    locationActivity = activity
    if (LocationService.Enabled) {
        if (!LocationServiceRunning) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                reportEvent("NOPERMIS")
                val errorNotif = createNotification(
                    activity,
                    "Error: location not available",
                    "Click to open settings and allow location access",
                    NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX,
                    Notification.CATEGORY_ERROR,
                    Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.fromParts("package", activity.packageName, null))
                )
                (activity.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).notify(99, errorNotif)
            } else {
                reportEvent("STARTING")
                createCount = 0
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { // Oreo = Android 8.0 = API level 26
                    activity.startForegroundService(locationIntent)
                } else {
                    activity.startService(locationIntent)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (LocationServiceRunning) {
            reportEvent("STOPPING")
            activity.stopService(locationIntent)
        } else {
            (activity.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).cancel(99) // Clean up any error notifications
        }
    }
}

fun reportEvent(event: String) {
    VolleyQueue.add(StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "${LocationService.ReportURL}&report=$event", {}, {}))
}

fun createNotification(activity: Activity, title: String, text: String, priority: Int, category: String?, intent: Intent): Notification {
    val channelID = "LOCATION_SERVICE"
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channelName = "Location Service"
        val chan = NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
        chan.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
        val manager = activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan)
    }
    return NotificationCompat.Builder(activity, channelID)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(if (text == "") null else text)
        .setPriority(priority)
        .setCategory(category)
        .setContentIntent(
            TaskStackBuilder.create(activity)
                .addNextIntent(intent)
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        )
        .setShowWhen(true)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .build()
}

class LocationService : Service() {
    companion object {
        var ReportURL: String = ""
        var ReportInterval: Long = 60000 // 60 Seconds
        var ReportTitle: String = "App is running"
        var ReportText: String = ""
        var Enabled: Boolean = false
    }

    private val startTime = now()
    private var locGPS: String = ""
    private var locCount = 0
    private var locTime = startTime
    private lateinit var locationTimer: Timer

    private fun now(): Int {
        return (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000).toInt()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        LocationServiceRunning = true
        createCount++
        if (Enabled) {
            showNotification()
            startLocationUpdates()
        }
    }

    private fun showNotification() {
        val locNotif = createNotification(
            locationActivity,
            ReportTitle,
            ReportText,
            NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN,
            Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE,
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        )
        startForeground(99, locNotif)
    }

    private fun startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return
        }
        locationTimer = fixedRateTimer("timer", false, 5000, ReportInterval * 1000) {
            val start = now() - startTime
            val last = now() - locTime
            VolleyQueue.add(StringRequest(  // https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple
                Request.Method.GET,
                "${ReportURL}&gps=$locGPS&count=$locCount&start=$start&last=$last&wait=${ReportInterval}&agent=App",
                { response ->
                    val lines = response.lines()
                    lines.forEach { line ->
                        when {
                            line == "start" -> startLocationService(applicationContext as MainActivity, true)
                            line == "stop" -> startLocationService(applicationContext as MainActivity, false)
                            line.startsWith("text:") -> ReportText = line.substring(5)
                            line.startsWith("title:") -> ReportTitle = line.substring(6)
                            line == "show" -> showNotification()
                            else -> Log.w("ø_LocationService", "bad response line: $line")
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    ReportTitle = "Error: connection lost"
                    ReportText = ""
                    showNotification()
                }
            ))
        }
        val request = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = ReportInterval
            fastestInterval = 20000
            priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }
        locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                val location: Location = locationResult.lastLocation
                locGPS = location.latitude.toString() + "," + location.longitude.toString()
                locCount++
                locTime = now()
            }
        }
        LocationServices
            .getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
            .requestLocationUpdates(request, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
        initialized = true
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        LocationServiceRunning = false
        if (initialized) {
            LocationServices
                .getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                .removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
            locationTimer.cancel()
        }
        if (Enabled) {
            reportEvent("RESTARTING")
            val broadcastIntent = Intent()
            broadcastIntent.action = "restartservice"
            broadcastIntent.setClass(this, LocationServiceRestarter::class.java)
            this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent)
        }
    }

}

class LocationServiceRestarter : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.i("ø_LocationService", "LocationServiceRestarter triggered")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context!!.startForegroundService(Intent(context, LocationService::class.java))
        } else {
            context!!.startService(Intent(context, LocationService::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

Can I avoid this memory leak without completely rewriting my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
private lateinit var locationActivity: Activity
```

What you need is a `Context` and your `LocationService` is a `Context`.

Change

```
fun startLocationService(activity: Activity, enable: Boolean) { ... }
fun createNotification(activity: Activity, ...) { ... }
```

to

```
fun startLocationService(context: Context, enable: Boolean) { ... }
fun createNotification(context: Context, ...) { ... }
```

and call `createNotification` passing as the first argument `this` instead of the `locationActivity`.

You can also use `applicationContext` instead of the `locationActivity` as you already do  when calling `startLocationService`.

Comment: This was a huge help. I am very inexperienced with Android apps and the whole "context vs activity" thing is still quite confusing for me. So thanks a lot!

Comment: @W3Coder, you are welcome! Highly recommend going through Google's training for Android like https://developer.android.com/courses and Core Developer Topics [here](https://developer.android.com/docs) one at a time. Don't try to understand it all at once. That will only confuse you. There is also a great number of Codelabs from Google that you can learn from: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=android